# Need to delete last column in every third line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

So far, I have the following code that allows me to loop through a file and identify the third line of every file. However, I want to delete the last column on every third line, but I'm having trouble coming up with the syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=1
lines=$(wc -l < 'test_file')
echo $lines

while read line; do
        if (( $counter % 3 == 0 )); then
                #Need a good one liner here to solve the problem!
        else
                echo "$line is not a multiple of three."
        fi
        ((counter = counter + 1))
done < 'test_file'
```

I'm open to using awk, but I'm not sure how to do that inline on a line within a file. If it can be done with parameters on the entire file that is fine.

Also, if the divisible by 3 line contains only one field, that should be deleted as well. There will never be an already existing blank line.

Sample input:

```
my dog smells
my cat bites
my fish swims
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Sample output:

```
my dog smells
my cat bites
my fish
a b c
d e f
g h
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is easier to handle this kind of task:

```
 awk 'NR%3==0{NF--}7' file
```

let's do a little test:

```
kent$  cat f
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d

kent$  awk 'NR%3==0{NF--}7' f
a b c d
a b c d
a b c
a b c d
a b c d
a b c
a b c d
a b c d
a b c
a b c d
```

Comment: @user3299633 non-zero number will apply awk's default action: `print`, which will print the current line

Comment: This is the desired solution, however, is there a way to handle blank lines without having the program crash?

Comment: `awk '!(NR%3) && NF{NF--} 1' file`

Comment: @user3299633 it means, if the line has at least one field. (the line is not empty), then delete the last field. well, there is a logical AND with the first part condition `!(NR%3)`

Comment: I guess I'm confused, I thought the ! meant to find lines that AREN'T divisible by three.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '3~3s/\s\S\+$//' file
```